# how to speed up redirect from http to https

Tags: http

I have a website that I built that is https only.

I have a redirect that rolls http to https via Javascript.
The problem is that the process lasts up to 4 seconds of wait time to reset connection and start https.

Is there a faster way to send http to https?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you serving the site? Nginx? Apache? I'm pretty sure that if this is the case, you can redirect using Nginx/Apache which is much faster.

Comment: You should use a 300-series HTTP redirect. Either a 301 permanent redirect or a 302 temporary redirect depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite HTTP requests to HTTPS requests using Nginx.

You can find an example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom).